# Azure web job graceful shutdown

Tags: c#, azure, shutdown, webjob

I am trying to implement graceful shutdown for a continuous Azure web job, provided the required job settings:

```
{
  "stopping_wait_time": 3600,
  "is_singleton":  true
}
```

I have registered the callback:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var cancellationToken = new WebJobsShutdownWatcher().Token;
        cancellationToken.Register(() =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Shutdown Started...");

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 5 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 10 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 15 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 20 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 25 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 30 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        });


        JobHost host = new JobHost();

        MethodInfo methodInfo =   typeof(Functions).GetMethod("GracefulShutdown");
        host.CallAsync(methodInfo);     //a long running method      
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

But on stopping the web job, I can never get the last line of the callback executed:

```
Console.WriteLine("Waited 30 seconds!" + DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> For triggered WebJobs there is no shutdown notification but there is a
>   graceful period (30 seconds by default) where the WebJob will not be
>   forcefully shutdown immediately, the graceful period is configurable.
>
> The graceful period can be updated for any WebJob, the way to do it is
>   to create a file called settings.job with the following content: {
>   "stopping_wait_time": 60 }

I can see that your graceful period is still 30 seconds which is the same as default. Please check if you have put your settings.job at right place. You put it in the same directory where you webjob executable is (I assume you uploaded a zip file through the portal? if so just put the settings file in the zip next to the .exe or .cmd you're using).

See http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.Vw3HdUcl_dV for more details.